# linker problems for EasyHook in Visual C++ 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, easyhook

I  have downloaded EasyHook 2.7 source and I try to compile it in my Visual Studio 2012 environment.

After solving a lot of warnings, I have found other warnings that I cannot solve, and these are:

```
1>error.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CoTaskMemAlloc@4 referenced in function _RtlGetLastErrorStringCopy@0
1>error.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CopyMemory@12 referenced in function _RtlGetLastErrorStringCopy@0
1>reloc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ud_init@4 referenced in function _LhDisassembleInstruction@20
1>reloc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ud_set_mode@8 referenced in function _LhDisassembleInstruction@20
1>reloc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ud_set_input_buffer@12 referenced in function _LhDisassembleInstruction@20
1>reloc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ud_set_syntax@8 referenced in function _LhDisassembleInstruction@20
1>reloc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ud_disassemble@4 referenced in function _LhDisassembleInstruction@20
1>reloc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ud_translate_intel@4 referenced in function _LhDisassembleInstruction@20
1>reloc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ud_set_asm_buffer@12 referenced in function _LhDisassembleInstruction@20
1>C:\Users\Jaime Stuardo\Downloads\EasyHook-2.7.5159.0-Source\\Debug\x86\EasyHook32Drv.sys : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
```

What lib files I need to add so that the linker will not fail? notice that the first 2 functions belong to Windows API, so it is very curious it does not link.

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

For the Windows functions, just look them up on MSDN.  [CoTaskMemAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says you need to link OLE32.LIB.  [CopyMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says KERNEL32.LIB.  The functions beginning with `ud` come from a library which [Easyhook depends on](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/):  "EasyHook makes use of the [udis86 library by Vivek](https://github.com/vmt/udis86).

Comment: For the project, these are the inherited libraries that are being linked: kernel32.lib
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
winspool.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
odbc32.lib
odbccp32.lib.... and these are additional libraries: ntoskrnl.lib
hal.lib
ntstrsafe.lib

Comment: Are you sure?  `CoTaskMemAlloc` is unresolved, so it seems OLE32.LIB is not being linked.

Comment: Of course.. please see this screnshot at http://www.desytec.com/build-error.png.... I use to develop C++ software in either Linux and Windows and I have never faced this problem.... since this code is more complex and not developed by me, I don't know what may cause this, Maybe other library is entering in conflict.